# Fragment Callbacks vs EventBus in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, callback, event-bus

I have faced with the problem. My `Activity` is fragment container, so to communicate between activity and fragments I used common `Callback` approach. In this case my activity has to implement tons of callback interfaces depending on fragment count.
I don't like to hardcode and unreadable code. In my case my class declaration can take several lines to list all interfaces.
I am trying to get rid of this.

There is another approach is to use `EventBus` pattern.
In activity

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

In fragment

```
EventBus.getDetault().post(new MyEvent(description));
```

And handle several event types in activity.

Maybe there will be better to use EventBus here instead default Callback approach ??
Or maybe there is my fault that my activity is holding a lot of fragments (God Object) and it is better to use activities instead Fragment ?

Please suggest which approach is better ?

Answer (score 4):

For simple one Activity to one Fragment hierarchy, callback is simplest decision to go. But think about Activity containing a Fragment, and the Fragment contains swipe-able `ViewPager`, and each tab of ViewPager has Fragments A,B,C.

The Fragment A,B,C will go to long journey to send event to mother Activity, and it can be lost interface connectivity between Activity and children when they are restored during [crazy complex Android Activity-Fragment lifecycle dances](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2014/08/complete-android-activity-and-fragment-lifecycle/). In this case, eventbus like [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) can be a good choice.

The drawback of event bus approach is, it is hard to maintain where the event is come from. So, keeping a few sender is recommended.

Comment: Wouldn't a `sender` property in MyEvenet give an idea who raised the event? OP has 
`EventBus.getDetault().post(new MyEvent(description));`

Comment: @OmarBizreh // yes. that helps. but we have to keep in mind that, the `sender` could be _null_.

Comment: I understand, so the only draw back is source of event, I'm going to start a new project and use EventBus, is there anything else I need to check? So far all SO links I saw mention that source of event is by far the worst draw back.

Answer (score 1):

Your `interface` approach is awesome, just keep up with them, and maybe try and slice/make your `interface` static and add all the little little `void`s and `return method`s to that interface so you can just implement one and call the functions.

`EventBus`? how about `LocalBroadcastReceiver` ? its a matter of preference and which one you feel will suit you better, after all if you handle 10,000 request and hate having 100 `interface`s, you will end up using 1 and nesting 99.

& just forgot, it is better to hold alot `Fragment` instead of `Activity` because at the end of the day the `Activity` lifecycle is pretty hard to maintain second of all you can not really control `Activity`ies well all as compared to `Fragment`s and `Fragment` is a good slave, serves you better

hope its valuable