# How to keep track of an instance of an event handler across fragments

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin android application that has a main fragment activity (named Home) which hosts a view pager and then several fragments in the view pager.

The application gets data from a bluetooth device that passes the data via an event handler once I instantiate the class.

```
BTScanner scanner = new BTScanner();
scanner.onScanData += BTScanner_onScanData;
```

The issue is, I need this event handler to be active on two of the fragments in my view pager, when that page is active. In other words, I want to receive the scan data if I am on fragment1 or fragment2, However, I can't have it go to both at the same time, there is processing of the data received and the processing is different based on which fragment you are receiving the scan data in.

What I have so far is I created a custom interface on the activity and implemented it in the fragments. It will allow me to call a method on the fragments when the view pager switches pages. Based on these methods, I can de-init the event handler on one page and init it on the other. Here is an example on the fragment activity:

```
    private void ViewPager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        int position = (int)e.Position;

        ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager fragmentToResume = (ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager)adapter.InstantiateItem(viewPager, position); 
        fragmentToResume.onResumePagerFragment(previousActiveFragment);

        ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager fragmentToPause = (ICustomFragmentLifecycleForPager)adapter.InstantiateItem(viewPager, previousActiveFragment);
        fragmentToPause.onPausePagerFragment();

        previousActiveFragment = position;
    }
```

Therefore, with this, I have it working as needed because when I implement the interface on the fragments, I get onPausePagerFragment called on the fragment I can de-init, and an onResumePagerFragment on the fragment I can init.

All that said, the issue I am having is actually on first startup. On first startup, I am setting the fragment to show first and when I do that, the

```
ViewPager_PageSelected
```

is not called initially, thus not calling my custom interface methods to init or de-init the scanner.

One thing I tried already is to put a method call in the onCreate of the activity (also tried it in onStartup and onResume) that would in theory only be called one time when the application starts and would then check which fragment is active at startup and force the interface methods to fire appropriately. However, this feels clunky and is not working properly. In addition to not working properly, I am also getting null exceptions in the fragment, when the interface method does fire because I force it to in onCreate of the activity, the method that is called by the interface on the fragment, onResumePagerFragment, returns a null for the activity here:

```
var activity = (Home)Activity;
```

This worked before and continues to work in other places in the code so I suspect that this is happening because the activity has not fully started yet before the interface calls the method on the fragment and it attempts to get a reference to the activity. Again, I tried doing this in onResume and onStart on the activity but I still get a null.

With all that said, what is the best way in general to handle a scenario like mine where I have the main activity which starts but then is nothing more than a fragment/view pager container and I need to have one instance to the event handler active on a fragment at a time? Should I even need to do an interface or rather use a static class? If I use a static class, I know how to get the instance of the class on each but how do you then create the event handler AND make sure to un-register is as well when another fragment grabs the instance?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not show you C# code, but below my answer could give you a hint.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30554102/361100

Note that Android natively provides `EventBus` and Xamarin I found is [MessageBus component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/messagebus) alternatively.

Secondly, you can make [Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/) so that the service is act as a delegator of all data communication whenever events are fired.

In conclusion, we could think Fragment does not gurantee to give same fragment when it restored and especially it is garbage-collected at any time when it's used with `ViewPager`.

Comment: I dont think I fully understand, I am still a bit of a noob. However, I would like the easiest approach and probably want to stay away from additional layers, like the service approach. Is there a simple approach to what I want to do? Is there some explanation as to why the Activity is null when my interface from the activity calls a method on the fragment? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelBedford // in case of your `null` after restore process, this post will help you. http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.kr/2014/05/fragment-lifecycle-with-respect-to-its.html The fragment is restored _before_ the activity. in this case, Activity is _null_ at the Fragment's side.

Comment: I read the article you posted and I am still a bit confused. I understand (even more so now that I read that article) the lifecycles. It would appear that I should not be having the issues I am having if I use onStart or even onResume in my activity. By then, not only should onCreate of the activity complete but also the fragment should be complete as well. Therefore, I should not be getting a null when accessing the activity from the fragment at that stage in the cycle, right?

Comment: Also, for all, I have been thinking about this since my OP and I think what I am thinking about doing is have the main fragment activity handle the event handler and the one instance of it. Then, I will have logic in the activity to determine where to and raise an event on the current fragment in the view pager. This is essentially "forwarding" an event from the main activity to event handlers on each fragment. I think that will work, right?

Comment: @MichaelBedford // Correct. That's why I described  in linked answer as _The Fragment A,B,C will go to long journey to send event to mother Activity_.

Comment: @MichaelBedford // The hardest thing for Android development is that, _nothing_ reliable. Activity can give null, Fragment can give null, event can not be fired, etc, even though you definitely see it.